# How to set wheelView items

Tags: android, custom-view

I find this https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView project in Github, and i can't realize how to set different items at different position in the wheelView. I want to add two items (ArrayList list)
Who can halp me please??

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WheelView wheelView;
private ArrayList<Drawable> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //This is the items I want to add
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loader));
    list.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twitter));
    ////

    wheelView = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.wheelView);

    wheelView.setAdapter(new WheelAdapter() {

        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(int position) {

            return ...;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return (int)wheelView.getItemCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
    });

}
}
```

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.roashviz.giftest2.MainActivity">



<com.lukedeighton.wheelview.WheelView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/wheelView"
    app:wheelColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:rotatableWheelDrawable="true"
    app:selectionAngle="270.0"
    app:wheelPosition=""
    app:wheelOffsetY="0dp"
    app:repeatItems="true"
    app:wheelRadius="150dp"
    app:wheelItemCount="2"
    app:wheelPadding="13dp"
    app:wheelItemRadius="43dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Thank!! :)

Comment: You mean the code needed in WheelView Adapter$getDrawable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to update your code like this, I didn't try it, but it should work

```
wheelView.setAdapter(new WheelAdapter() {

@Override
public Drawable getDrawable(int position) {

    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}
});
```

Comment: How can i use custom views with this ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this up and running would be to look inside the sample project associated with the library you are trying to use:

[MainActivityCode](https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView/blob/master/WheelViewSample/src/main/java/com/lukedeighton/wheelsample/MainActivity.java)

You will also find useful information by exploring the other files:

[TextDrawable](https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView/blob/master/WheelViewSample/src/main/java/com/lukedeighton/wheelsample/TextDrawable.java)

You can even download the whole thing and try it yourself before using the library to at least make sure it works!

I hope this gives you an idea on what you need to do!